# css pseudo element is hidden by subsequent container with float property

Tags: html, css, sass

I have two columns

1. Tab navigation
2. Tab form

The tab navigation column has a couple of links which upon click would open a form in the 2nd column

I'm setting up a tool-tip for each link in the tab navigation column like the below (`.scss`)

```
ul{
  .tooltip{
    // display: inline;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    &:hover:after{
      background: #333;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
      border-radius: 5px;
      bottom: -5px;
      color: #fff;
      content: attr(title);
      // left: 140%;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: auto;
    }
    &:hover:before{
      border: solid;
      border-color: #333 transparent;
      border-top: 6px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
      border-right: 6px solid #727272;
      bottom: 5px;
      content: "";
      left: 125%;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99;
    }
  }
}
```

However , the tooltips seem to appear hidden by the form container despite giving them a higher z-index.

[image]

The form column does not have a z-index and has a `float:left` attribute set.

How do i have the after element come on top of the form column.

**EDIT: it appears as though the width is restricted by the width of the tabnav parent **

[image]

the `.tab-nav` has the following css (using bourbon neat)

```
  .tab-nav {
    @include span-columns(4);
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: That's not valid CSS, are you using a pre-compiler of some sort? (Sass, Less etc etc) If so, it's worth pointing that out in the question and tags.

Comment: Oops .. yes .. i'm using scss

Comment: Are you certain that the element is behind the form column? Have you tried setting a background colour to the before/after pseudo elements?

Comment: @DanielYoung - i gave it a background .. it still seems to be getting cut by the form container

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a [pen](http://codepen.io/pen/) or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @DanielYoung - i added another picture .. would this help?

Comment: Is there an `overflow: hidden` or `overflow-x: hidden` in the `@span-columns` mix-in which is causing the clipping?

Comment: Actually no .. i even tried changing overflow-x : visible to over-ride it. Still doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The part of your  `.tooltip` is hidden because its parent has `overflow-x: hidden`.

Either set `position: absolute` for the tooltip or `overflow-x: visible` for `.tab-nav`